# ionic status bar issue white - iOS

Tags: ios, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am creating a mobile application with Ionic framework , When i test it with iOS device my status bar turn into white color after the application is fully loaded. I need to change the color from white to black. It works fine with Android Device.

This is the issue

[image]

I tried the following methods and nothing works

I made change to my config.xml file which was mentioned in many website as following

```
<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="true" />
<preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#000000" />
<preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="lightcontent" />
```

I further added the statusbar native event handlers under my app.component.ts

```
constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      statusBar.backgroundColorByHexString('#000000');
      statusBar.show();
      splashScreen.hide();
    });
```

is there a better solution to solve this issue.

The HTML of this project

app.html

```
<ion-nav [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>
```

Comment: Could you please show us the HTML file for this page.

Comment: i have updated the HTML you can check it

Comment: How are you testing, just `ionic serve`? Try `ionic emulate ios` if you have not done so.  I had this issue as well and when I emulated it appeared as the color I wanted (in my case white).

Comment: i perform ionic cordova build ios to build the application and install it via xcode